# I cannot select text on my website and the text input fields do not work

Tags: wordpress

I've been having this issue for a couple of months now. It's been a thorn on my side.

If you go to mcgrathrealtyinc.com, you will notice that you won't be able to select or highlight any text and the text fields on the forms do not work.

I've already done the plugin compatibility test and changed themes, but I'm still having the same problem.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend disabling plugins one at a time until you identify the cause. If you disable javascript in the browser the text can be selected so you're looking for a javascript file that is included - by the theme or a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited your site and inspected the event listeners and saw a file **wprmenu.js** using the mouseup eventlistener.

Blocking this file in the browser fixes the issue, the path of the file reveals the plugin name **wp-responsive-menu**

http://mcgrathrealtyinc.com/2017/wp-content/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/js/wprmenu.js?ver=1.0

I suggest replacing the plugin or contacting the support page [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-responsive-menu) and asking if some can see what the exact problem is.

Comment: omg! thank you so much! This has been right under my nose. Thank you for pointing out this specific plugin to me. I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)